# Terraform 0.12 Lambda and Beanstalk package deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

Before when deploying lambda code, we tell to our terraform code on which s3 bucket to look and deploy on the lambda infrastructure.
Nowadays devops guys can deploy lambda code via terraform by simply providing the absolute path on where the code is stored from local.

Is terraform capable too to use this approach on deploying beanstalk application bundle?

I'm deploying my lambda code on this kind of fashion (sample below), can this be also doable on deploying elasticbeanstalk application bundle?

```
  data "archive_file" "my_lambda" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "../../my_lambda"
  output_path = "../../my_lambda.zip"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "my_lambda" {
  function_name    = "my_lambda"
  filename         = data.archive_file.my_lambda.output_path
  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.my_lambda.output_base64sha256
  handler          = "src/my_lambda.handler"
  role             = aws_iam_role.my_lambda.arn
  runtime          = "nodejs12.x"
  memory_size      = "128"
  timeout          = "60"
  environment {
    variables = {
      VAR1                = var.VAR1
      VAR2                = var.VAR2
      VAR3                = var.VAR3
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean exactly, but you can prepare deployment package in zip in terraform, upload it to S3 and the use in EB application version to deploy it.

You can use [archive_file](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/archive/latest/docs/data-sources/archive_file) to zip your application's folder:

```
data "archive_file" "ebzip" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "/path/to/my-eb-app"
  output_path = "/tmp/my-eb-app.zip"
}
```

Then you could use [aws_s3_bucket_object](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_object) to upload it to your deployment bucket:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "ebapp" {
  bucket = "your_bucket_name"
  key    = "new_object_key"
  source = archive_file.ebzip.output_path
}
```

End then you can use that in your [aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elastic_beanstalk_application_version):

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version" "default" {
  name        = "tf-test-version-label"
  application = "tf-test-name"
  description = "application version created by terraform"
  bucket      = "your_bucket_name"
  key         = aws_s3_bucket_object.ebapp.id
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking Marcin, I'm no longer relying on S3 bukcet when deploying my code on lambda. I modified my question above and showing how I am deploying my lambda code. I would like to know if anyone already tried this kind of approach on deploying application bundle in beanstalk using terraform

Comment: @Lagot I see. Sadly, I'm not aware of such a possibility for EB. I think its only limited to lambda.

Comment: thanks for looking by @Marcin. seems like it really is limited only on lambda

Comment: @Lagot No problem. If you find some better way, please let me know. I'm also curious.